# Android: Boot BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: java, android

My application is deigned to start a `BroadcastReceiver` when the phone boots up, however i get a `NullPointerException`. I'm not sure if I'm setting up the receivers properly.

The error i got when booting up the device, using the adb logcat command:

```
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.idkbro.pashchallenge, PID: 6465
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.idkbro.pashchallenge.BootReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2992)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1544)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4868)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.idkbro.pashchallenge.BootReceiver.<init>(BootReceiver.java:24)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2987)
12-01 09:46:12.542  6465  6465 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 8 more
```

The BootReceiver class:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
        Log.i("Xu", "Boot receiver is working");


    }

  }
}
```

The Manifest for it:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: @Piyush, this isn't a duplicate. You should read question before closing it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Its a duplicate for _NullPointerException_. Stacktrace shows error for NPE. Atleast OP should know what is NPE?

Comment: Is it a complete source of your BootReceiver.java? have you removed something from it before posting? What is the 24th line of BootReceiver.java?

Comment: @Piyush, but the question, that marked as duplicated byt this completely not answers this question since NPE happens inside Android SDK, not in OP's class. This really is not *yet another `I have NPE, please help me` question*

Comment: Its all about NPE. Error log clearly says that Package name is null

Comment: @Piyush, please read my comment carefully: **that question does not answers this question**. I'm sure you have just saw `NullPointerException` word, and closed the question because it contains `NullPointerException` word. Please stop harming SO community.

Comment: I have read your comment too and yes i am not harming SO community. I am also the part of SO.

Comment: @Piyush, if you want to comment me, use @ <my username>. And yes, you are harming the community. closing questions wich shouldn't be closed

Comment: @Piyush I sorry for the senseless question, I know what a NPE, really. In my case i just really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Fay12Keh32, what is on line 24 of your `BootReceiver.java`?

Comment: is com.idkbro.pashchallenge the main package of your application?

Comment: @franklinexpress yes it is.

Comment: create a new package and put the reveiver in it, update your manifest appropiately

Comment: @Fay12Keh32, will you answer my question?

Comment: @VladMatvienko It was in intent that i commented out because i wanted to get the receiver working first.

Comment: @Fay12Keh32, are you using `Instant Run`? I think that your app on device uses old code with not commented 24 line

Comment: @VladMatvienko (sorry for the late reply)  Yes, i think i am using instant run.

Comment: @VladMatvienko The error still persists even when i run the code as a whole.(Without any comments)

Comment: 1. show the whole code. 2. disable instant run. It is buggy-as-hell

Comment: @VladMatvienko I'll try now and update you.

Comment: @VladMatvienko, I think the code was outdated (I'm still not sure why because i ran it so much times). Thank you very much for helping, really greatful :

Comment: @Fay12Keh32, that happened because of Instant Run. Don't use it better.